# Angular2 - Angular Datatable using suscribe

Tags: angular, datatable

Im trying to use **[Angular datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)** with angular2. The code is similar to this

```
myArray: any;

function test() {
    callService subscribe((response) => {
        this.myArray = response['body'];
    })
    this.datatableOptions();
}

datatableOptions() {
    this.dtOptions = {
        order: [1, "desc"],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        pageLength: 100,
        lengthMenu: [
            [100, 150, 200, -1],
            [100, 150, 200, "Todo"]
        ],
        responsive: true,
        rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
            var api = this.api();
            $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index + (api.page() * api.page.len() + 1));
        },
        processing: true,
        searching: true,
        deferRender: true,
        data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myArray)),
        columns: [{
                targets: 0,
                data: null
            },
            {
                targets: 1,
                data: 'A',
                defaultContent: '-'
            },
            {
                targets: 2,
                data: 'B',
                defaultContent: '-'
            },
            {
                targets: 3,
                data: 'C',
                defaultContent: '-'
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

The problem: *console.log(response['body'])* has data, but datatable doesn´t show any data. So, what´s wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the function doesn't know "**this**".
In the subscribe function, "this" is the scope of the function, not the component.

You can avoid it with this trick:

```
myArray: any;

function test() {
    let thisContext = this;
    callService subscribe((response) => {
        thisContext.myArray = response['body'];
    })
    this.datatableOptions();
}
```

So you bind the "this" scope when you enter in the test function to the thisContext variable.
Inside the subscribe function, you refer to that scope with the thisContext variable.

In this way, you should find the myArray variable populated with the data.

Comment: Mmm, return  Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Add `[dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"` to your table tag in html.

Import this `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';` to your type script and initialize dtTrigger as `dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();`

After you assign data `this.myArray = response['body'];` just add
`this.dtTrigger.next();` to manually re-render the data.

If this still doesn't resolve the issue then destroy the data table first and manually re-render as `$('#dataTableID').DataTable().clear().destroy(); this.dtTrigger.next();`